# Curly braces or round parentheses, which one is better to reference variables?

Tags: makefile

Which one is better and should be applied? `${var}` or `$(var)`

```
# Rule using $()
$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -o $(TARGET) $(OBJECTS)

# Rule using ${}
$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    ${CXX} ${CXXFLAGS} -o ${TARGET} ${OBJECTS}
```

Comment: In general StackOverflow is not appropriate for "opinion" questions like "which is the best XYZ".  There is absolutely no difference, in make, between the usage of these two and so the technical / non-opinion answer is, neither one is better and both are 100% equivalent.